# Error while creating a list to populate a combo box

Tags: python, function, wxpython, return-value

I have spent the last hour trying to see what I'm doing wrong, or overlooking. I'm attempting to populate a combobox based on the file extension of the file a user chooses. Below are the key pieces of my code. Thanks for any help:

```
...
unit1 = 'myfile.avi'
...
...

if self.format_combo1 != 'Select Media' or self.format_combo1 != '':
        myFormat = self.format_combo1.GetValue

formats2 =['.avi','.mpeg','.mp4','.flv','.mov','.mpeg4','.mpg','.mp3','.ogg','.wav','.wma']
    FormTypes = [self.formatType(myFormat, formats2)]# Function call here
    self.format_combo2=wx.ComboBox(panel, size=(100, -1),value='Select Format', choices=FormTypes, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN, pos=(300,81))

...
...

def formatType(self, unit1, formats2):
    auDio = ['.wav','.wma','.mp3','.ogg']
    viDeo = ['.avi','.mpeg','.mp4','.flv','.mov','.mpeg4','.mpg']
    bad_format = ['Invalid Format']
    fileExtension = os.path.splitext(unit1)[1]
    if fileExtension in formats2:
        if fileExtension in auDio:
            return auDio
        elif fileExtension in viDeo:
            return viDeo
    else:

        return bad_format
```

Below is the traceback message that I'm getting:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GVRSQA004\Desktop\D_Converter\med_convrt.py", line 499, in <module>
  frame = dConvert()
  File "C:\Users\GVRSQA004\Desktop\D_Converter\med_convrt.py", line 112, in __init__
  self.format_combo2=wx.ComboBox(panel, size=(100, -1),value='Select Format',          choices=FormTypes, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN, pos=(300,81))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line 590, in   __init__
 _controls_.ComboBox_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_ComboBox(*args, **kwargs))
 TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

Comment: What is the type of `myFormat` (check with `type(myFormat)`) ? It appears to be a function instead of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myFormat = self.format_combo1.GetValue
```

You're assigning `myFormat` a function object here (probably you meant `GetValue()`). Then, you're calling `formatType` with `myFormat` as the first argument, which is expected to be a string.